# How to identify number of instances of azure app server in scale-out scenarios programmatically?

Tags: c#, azure-web-app-service

I am developing a chat application using SignalR. In case of scaleout scenarios it is difficult for me to send messages to a particular user as it may be connected on different instance. For that I have used service bus to communicate with other instances. Right now I am sending the message when I don't find it on current instance without knowing that if other instances exists or not. Therefore, I need to make sure if it is possible for me identify that programatically or not?

We cannot use Azure SignalR service (as some suggested to move in that direction) as we need to make sure it depends less on cloud for future development.

Comment: i dont think its being exposed in the [system variables](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Azure-runtime-environment) so you'd need to query the api

Comment: @4c74356b41 I have explored the [api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/appservice/appserviceenvironments) but could not find the desired one. Could you provide some reference against it if there is any.

Comment: multiRoleCount or stampCapacity.totalCapacity or multiSize [on this api call](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/appservice/appserviceenvironments/get). One of those would be it most likely (i suspect totalCapacity)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the API below to get the current instance number of your web app server(app service plan):

```
GET https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/<sub ID>/resourceGroups/<resource group name>/providers/Microsoft.Web/serverfarms/<service plan name>?api-version=2018-02-01
```

If you get the response successfully ,you can find the number of instance in `properties.currentNumberOfWorkers` : 
[image]
Hope it helps .

Comment: Hi @Stanley, from where I can find Authentication token to read server info.

Comment: Hi @AbdulWahabButt , you can find the steps that how you can get an access token from Azure AD to all Azure management rest API : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/#create-the-request